# Showing text in tkinter´s canvas repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I´m trying to use tkinter in order to show a popup window in front of all other windows that reminds me of something through a text displayed in the canvas. I want that the window pops up during some time, eg 5 seconds, and then dissapear for other time. I need this to repeat in a loop. When i tried to do it, a window appear but without the text and the specified dimensions. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep as s


for i in range(5):

    root = Tk()

    root.lift()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    canvas = Canvas(root,width=700,height=100)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_text(350,50,text='Registrar rabia'+str(i),font= 
    ('fixedsys','25'))
    print('Hola')
    s(1)
    root.destroy()
    s(1)
```

Also, is there a more pythonic way to do it?

EDIT:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

for _ in range(6):
    #root.deiconify()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    root.title("About this application...")
    about_message = 'Este es el mensaje'
    msg = Message(root, text=about_message)
    msg.pack()

    button = Button(root, text="Dismiss", command=root.withdraw)

    button.pack()
    root.after(1000)
```

It didn´t work. I need only one message and one button, and in the code above,
python shows 6 messages and 6 buttons... Also i need to put a delay between appearances but i can´t understand  how to use the after method in this particular case.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `time.sleep` in a GUI program, because it freezes _everything_, so the GUI can't function correctly. Also, it's not very efficient to re-create and destroy the Tk interpreter like that. Check out the Toplevel widget.

Comment: Why are you creating and destroying the window over and over? Create the window once, then just hide and show it.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I tried to use it with 'root.withdraw()' function, but the problem is how to show it again in the next iteration

Comment: `root.deiconify()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I use it as in the  code of the edited section of my question, but gives me the same behavior